# ImportError: No module named _io

Tags: python

When I compile my python scripts I'm getting the following error message. This started happening when I installed Anaconda. I've tried to find a solution online to the problem but I've had no luck. Can anyone help with solving this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "query.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .connection import MySQLConnection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 27, in <module>
    from io import IOBase
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: No module named _io
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using virtualenv? When I ran into this issue it was because of some server update which messed with the python version being used by my virtualenv. I solved the problem by deleting the virtualenv and making a new identical one.